# Point coordinates at a fixed distance from a vector

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, coordinate-systems

I would like to solve the following generic problem by using vector notation that I will use it to improve my algorithm.

I have a vector P1P2 that points P1 and P2 are known. Furthermore, an arbitrary point P(xp,yp) and perpendicular distance from point A and P,  d=|AP| is known. The only unknown is the point A(xa,ya).

By using the distance formula and solving for A should solve the problem geometrically, but the question is how this can be done by using vectors? In addition, I know that there will be two solutions, one on LHS and one on RHS of the vector, I would like to be able to include both cases as well.

Thanks for your replies in advance!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you're in the plane. If so:
\begin{align}
\mathbf s = P_2 - P_1\\
\mathbf u = \frac{\mathbf s}{\| \mathbf s \|} \\
\mathbf v = d \begin{bmatrix} -u_y \\ u_x\end{bmatrix}\\
A = P + \mathbf v
\end{align}

Here $u_x$ and $u_y$ denote the components of the vector $\mathbf u$.

Details: I'm assuming you're willing to add a vector to a point to get a new vector, and subtract two points to get a vector. I like to think of vectors as "displacements," in which case those two operations make a lot of sense.

The only subtle operation is turning a vector $\begin{bmatrix} p \\q\end{bmatrix}$ into the vector $\begin{bmatrix} -q \\p\end{bmatrix}$, which rotates it 90 degrees counterclockwise. You can think of this as a 2D cross product (which takes only *one* argument, not two), so that $\mathbf v,  \times \mathbf v$ is, for any nonzero vector $\mathbf v$, a positively oriented basis of $\mathbb R^2$, just as $\mathbf v,  \mathbf w, v\times \mathbf w$ is a positively oriented basis for $\mathbb R^3$ for two independent vectors in 3-space.

Comment: Yes I am in the 2D plane, but I could not understand what lowercase "a" in 3rd row in your solution correspond to?

Comment: Sorry...I read that "d" in your diagram as an "a" (old eyes!). Fixed now.

Comment: Thank you. Now it seems clear and works all right. One small question is that, when I want the point on right hand side of the line, I should multiply with the the opposite signs for v vector and do all the remaining the same, shouldn't I?
\begin{align}
\mathbf v = d \begin{bmatrix} u_y \\ -u_x\end{bmatrix}\\
\end{align}

Or just use a negative d value and use all the same vector operations?

Comment: If you mean "to your right, as you walk from $P_1$ to $P_2$, then yes, you should use a negative value for $d$. In my formula, you should think of $d$ as "how far to the left of the (directed) line you want the resulting point to be", so negative $d$ values get you points to the right of the directed line.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this solution works flawlessly. I am marking it as accepted answer. Thank you for your time and help @John Hughes